# What is the difference between gets() and scanf()

Tags: c, string, scanf, gets, letters

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char text[100];
   int length = 0;

   gets(text);

   while (text[length] != '\0')
      length++;

   printf("%d",length);
}
```

I was trying to count the letters in an string using the above program. it worked. But, when i tried the same program with `scanf()` instead of `gets()`, it didn't work.

Comment: `man gets`, then `man scanf`

Comment: It would be very helpful to see how you used `scanf()`.

Comment: That's because you entered words separated by spaces, right?

Answer (score 1):

`gets(buf)` and `scanf("%[^\n]", buf)` are equivalent and **MUST NOT BE USED** because they will read input beyond the end of `buf`.

Use `fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)` and adjust you code for the fact that `fgets` stores the `'\n'` at the end of `buf` if present in the input stream.

Comment: `scanf("%99[^\n]", buf)` is perfectly safe if the definition was `char buf[100];`

Comment: That true, but it is very cumbersome to use the size limitation for buffers with a non trivial size, such as `buf[BUFSIZ]`.  Not to mention the lack of similarity between `99` and `100` which prevents peripheral vision checks.  It is really too bad the specifier syntax for `scanf` is inconsistent with that of `printf`. It should have been: `scanf("%*s", (int)sizeof(buf), buf);` but history cannot be rewritten.

Comment: @pmg `gets()` fails is the input is too long.  `scanf("%99[^\n]", buf)` fails if the input is too short - only `'\n'`.

Comment: @chux: `scanf("%99[a]", ...)` means "scan **up to** 99 a's"

Comment: `scanf("%99[a]", ...)` actually matches a **non-empty** sequence of up to 99 `'a'` characters.  chux is right, `scanf` cannot match `gets` function exactly, both are mostly misunderstood.

Comment: @chux: Where "fails" means "exhibits undefined behavior with arbitrarily bad consequences but no required error detection".

Comment: I guess it `scanf("%99[^\n]", buf)` returns 0 on an empty input line and leaves `buf` untouched.  If `buf` is uninitialized, its contents are indeterminate and undefined behaviour may ensue if `scanf`s return value is not tested and `buf` is used carelessly.

Comment: @pmg The shortcoming of `scanf("%99[a]", ...)` is that is scans `1` up to `99` a's and not **up to** 99 a's.  If input does not begin with `a`, then `buf` does not take on the value of `""`, instead, it is left as is.

Comment: yes!!! Always check the return value: `if (scanf(...) != <EXPECTED_VALUE>) /* error */;`